# foreach on returned XML string from a service

Tags: xml, parsing

I have the following code that works great when the service only returns one item... but in most cases it will return many items.  I cannot seem to figure out how to do a simple foreach on the items.

```
DataReference.USZipSoapClient blah = new DataReference.USZipSoapClient("USZipSoap");
var results = blah.GetInfoByCity(tbCityName.Text).InnerXml;

//Response.Write(results);
XmlDocument docArticle = new XmlDocument();
docArticle.LoadXml(results);

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

XmlNodeList nodeCity = docArticle.ChildNodes[0].SelectNodes("CITY");
XmlNodeList nodeState = docArticle.ChildNodes[0].SelectNodes("STATE");
XmlNodeList nodeZip = docArticle.ChildNodes[0].SelectNodes("ZIP");
XmlNodeList nodeAreaCode = docArticle.ChildNodes[0].SelectNodes("AREA_CODE");
XmlNodeList nodeTimeZone = docArticle.ChildNodes[0].SelectNodes("TIME_ZONE");

builder.Append(nodeCity[0].InnerText + "<br/>");
builder.Append(nodeState[0].InnerText + "<br/>");
builder.Append(nodeZip[0].InnerText + "<br/>");
builder.Append(nodeAreaCode[0].InnerText + "<br/>");
builder.Append(nodeTimeZone[0].InnerText + "<br/>");

lblCityName.Text = builder.ToString();
```

The data being returned for one itme looks like this. As I mentioned however most results bring back many items not just one.

```
<NewDataSet xmlns=""><Table><CITY>Marana</CITY><STATE>AZ</STATE><ZIP>85653</ZIP><AREA_CODE>520</AREA_CODE><TIME_ZONE>M</TIME_ZONE></Table></NewDataSet>
```

Any Help is appreciated!

Comment: In general, you should include the language in your question. Is this C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[Linq To XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)** which comes with a `XDocument` class and it much more easier to work with that class than `XmlDocument`.

Before using that class you must reference `System.Xml.Linq` and import the namespace with the same name.

With `XDocument` you can write the following code:

```
var docArticle = XDocument.Parse(results);
var results = docArticle.Element("NewDataSet").Elements().Select(elt => new
{
    City = elt.Element("CITY") != null ? elt.Element("CITY").Value : string.Empty,
    State = elt.Element("STATE") != null ? elt.Element("STATE").Value : string.Empty,
    Zip = elt.Element("ZIP") != null ? elt.Element("ZIP").Value : string.Empty,
    AreaCode = elt.Element("AREA_CODE") != null ? elt.Element("AREA_CODE").Value : string.Empty,
    TimeZone = elt.Element("TIME_ZONE") != null ? elt.Element("TIME_ZONE").Value : string.Empty,
}).ToList();

// Here do what you want with the results variable
```